# How to find out what codec is used in a video

Tags: release-freya, sound, codec, videos

How to find what codec was used in a video (Audio/Video) and extra information like in `nautilus`. The below screenshot is from nautilus.

[image: Imgur]

Is there any *GUI* way to find codec information, without shifting from file manager?

Is it possible to get the details in `pantheon-files` ?

I have already tried `mediainfo-gui`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete GUI information, but the next solution to it, I think. On [Github](http://rrevanth.github.io/blog/elementary-contracts) there are contracts among other for video and audio information: Create a file in `/usr/share/contractor`

- Open Scratch as root `gksudo scratch-text-editor` (in order to create the file in `/usr/share/contractor`).
- Create a new file and copy and paste following lines.
- Save as `mediainfo.contract`
- Log out.

**For video:**

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Media info
Icon=video
Description=media info
MimeType=video
Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=new1 -e "mediainfo -i %f"
Gettext-Domain=pantheon-files
```

**For audio:**

```
[Contractor Entry]
Name=Media info
Icon=video
Description=media info
MimeType=audio
Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=new1 -e "mediainfo -i %f"
Gettext-Domain=pantheon-files
```

**EDIT:** Seems that Scratch does not create the right file type, so use gedit instead.

Comment: Can you provide details instead of links :)